# Spring Hibernate not committing data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, transactions

I have a Spring MVC application we're developing, using Spring 4.2.3 and Hibernate 5.0.6. In some of our testing we found that some of our data is not being saved to the database (Oracle).  The code is as follows:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class MyService {
    @Autowired
    private MyDao dao;

    public void saveCustomer(Customer c) {
        dao.saveCustomer(c);
    }
}

@Repository
@Transactional
public class MyDao {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;   // Hibernate's SessionFactory

    public void saveCustomer(Customer cust) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().clear();
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(cust);
    }
}
```

To be honest, I just saw that @Transactional on MyDao, as I'm writing this.  That probably is wrong, since @Transactional is already on the service layer.

We're using Java Config....showing the relevant beans....

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({"my.package"})
public class Config extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(ComboPooledDataSource dataSource) {
    LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
    sessionBuilder.scanPackages("my.entities"); 
    sessionBuilder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
    return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);    
    return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

My question is, other than the @Transactional on MyDao, which shouldn't be there, is there anything else that stands out to anyone as to why Customer does not save to the database?  Are we even doing transactions correctly?  I've never liked using Hibernate's SessionFactory, but that's the way we went.  Are we using it correctly within a Spring Transaction?

Thanks!

Chris

Comment: What are those scenarios in which some of your data is not being saved to the database? Is there any exception?

Comment: No exceptions.  I tested that as well with a try/catch.  In the debugger, the customer info is getting read in from the webpage, being put into a Customer bean, but then after calling service.saveCustomer(customer) the customer data is not in the database.

Comment: remove `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().clear(); sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();` from `saveCustomer` and try.

Comment: no effect.  same results.  I also tried putting the flush() after the save(customer) but still same results.  Did also remove the @Transactional from the DAO class.  Same results.

Comment: No error at all? Put your minimal executable code in github and let us try that.